# How calculate filtered by date aggregate sum after grouping by some column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have a table which contains payments received by person per date. I.e.

```
person  paymentDate  money
--------------------------
Smith   01-01-2020   567
Black   01-01-2020   780
```

We know how to calculate aggregate sum in SQL:

```
select person,sum(money) from personIncomeByDate group by person
```

We know how to calculate aggregated sum for some period of dates:

```
select person,sum(money) 
from personIncomeByDate 
where paymentDate = '12-12-2020' 
group by person
```

Here is the question: what if I need last aggregate but I dont want to remove persons which never had payments on 12-12-2020?
In other words, after grouping and summing I want to see something like that

```
person | moneySumFor12-12-2020
------------------------------
Smith  | 300
Black  | 0
King   | 245
```

Probably I can achieve this with join, but this looks like an overhead. Any options?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use operator `CASE`:

```
SELECT person, 
SUM (CASE WHEN paymentDate='12-12-2020' THEN money ELSE 0 END)moneySum
FROM personIncomeByDate
GROUP BY person
```

If you need to get several dates then use predicate `IN`:

```
SELECT person, 
SUM (CASE WHEN paymentDate IN ('12-12-2020', '10-12-2020'...) THEN money ELSE 0 END)moneySum
FROM personIncomeByDate
GROUP BY person
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to enumerate the distinct `person`s, and then bring the original table with a `left join`:

```
select p.person, coalesce(sum(money), 0) sum_money
from (select distinct person from personIncomeByDate) p
left join personIncomeByDate i 
    on  i.person = p.person
    and i.paymentDate = date '2020-12-12' 
group by p.person
```

I am suspicious about the date literal in your original query: are you really storing dates as strings in format `'dd-mm-yyyy'`? I made the assumption that you have actual an `date`-like datatype, and hence passed the value as a standard literal date: you might need to adapt this to your actual use case and database.

Side note: in a real life situation, you would probably have a separate table to store the persons, that you would use instead of a `select distinct` subquery:

```
select p.person, coalesce(sum(money), 0) sum_money
from persons p
left join personIncomeByDate i 
    on  i.person = p.person
    and i.paymentDate = date '2020-12-12' 
group by p.person
```

Comment: GMB, this works, but the solution with CASE looks simplier, right?

Answer (score 1):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
select person
       sum(case when paymentDate = '12-12-2020' then money else 0 end) as sum_12122020
from personIncomeByDate 
group by person;
```

This only includes people who have had some payment.

Note that `'12-12-2020'` is a really, really bad format for a date.  You should be storing dates using internal formats -- `date` or `datetime` data types for instance.  Then the comparison should use a standard format, YYYY-MM-DD.